# Why is Microsoft.PythonTools.Attacher.exe blocking Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

At least two or three times a day Visual Studio gets stuck (in a deadlock I suspect) and displays the spinning-toilet-bowl-of-death cursor and pops up the dreaded "*Microsoft Visual Studio is Busy*" notification in the notification area:

[image]

It used to be that when this happened Visual Studio would stay like that for hours (and possibly until the end of time itself or a power cut) unless I kicked it to the kerb with an "End Process" in task manager.

More recently I noticed another process always seemed to be lurking about whenever this problem arises - [`Microsoft.PythonTools.Attacher.exe`](http://pytools.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fd5dab3d30f4#Release/Product/Python/Attacher/Attacher.csproj) - which is part of the [Python Tools for Visual Studio project](http://pytools.codeplex.com/):

[image]

If I kill that process then Visual Studio manages to free itself from whatever deadly embrace it's got itself into and can continue on its way, and this is what I look out for every time VS does this.

Whilst I do have Python Tools for Visual Studio 1.0 installed, the projects I am working on are plain old ASP.NET MVC3 apps written in C#. I'm not using any Python code or libraries and often I only have one instance of Visual Studio running.

What I also observe is that this process doesn't always start/appear for whole development sessions, and when it does, it seems to start up an random times (i.e. it's not there for the first hour or two and then it magically appears in the process list in task manager), but when it does I know I'm going be in trouble at some point.

Does anyone know why this process seems to randomly start and why it's interfering with Visual Studio in such a dramatic fashion?

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 Premium SP1 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do Debug->Attach to Process you'll see that VS displays a list of processes and along with them it displays the types of code that you can debug which are running in those processes.  To get this information VS queries the various installed debug engines.  So when we get queried we go and inspect a bunch of processes to see what's going on.  If it's a 32 bit process life is easy - we can use various APIs to enumerate the modules and try and figure out if there's a Python interpreter in the process.  If it's a 64-bit process life is a little tougher because we're running inside of VS and it's a 32-bit process.  We can't use the APIs from a 32-bit to a 64-bit process so instead we spawn a helper process to do the work.

It sounds like this helper process is somehow becoming a zombie on your system.  It'd be great if you could attach VS to it and send any stack traces back in a bug.  But we should also provide some defense in depth and timeout if the helper process isn't responding.

Finally killing it should generally be safe, it's not doing anything stateful, and we'll start a new one when we need it.

If you never use Debug->Attach to Process for Python debugging there's probably a trivial file update to our .pkgdef file which I could track down and post which would make this problem go away entirely.

Comment: Thanks Dino, I'll open a bug as suggested with more data once this happens again....now I just have to wait :).

Comment: And...sods law I am still waiting :/

Comment: Hey Dino, I've long since moved on from VS2010. Your answer nicely explains the mechanics so I'll mark as accepted, thanks for your efforts all the same.